# Не подключить MySql в React

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

Решил написать приложение на React. Мне нужно получить данные из бд mysql.

Есть код:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "user",
        database: "database",
        password: "password"
      });
connection.connect(function(err){
        if (err) {
          return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
        }
        else{
          console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
        }
     });

connection.query("SELECT * FROM users;",
      function(err, results, fields) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(results);
        console.log(fields);
    });
    connection.end(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log("Ошибка: " + err.message);
        }
        console.log("Подключение закрыто");
      });
```

На что я получил ошибку:

```
TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function
```

Что я делаю не так?

Доп. вопрос - Как скрыть пароль от бд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реакт - это фронтэнд, то есть всё, что доступно любому пользователю, поэтому подключение к БД там быть не может, иначе любой пользователь сможет воспользоваться вашим паролем.

Вам нужно создать бэкэнд и уже там подключаться к БД. Из реакта же вы будете делать запросы к бэкэнду.

Если не хотите создавать бэкэнд, воспользуйтесь next.js - там есть встроенный бэкэнд.

Comment: Выше код это Node.JS и документация: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp.